# Displaying icons dynamically in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to load part of my website dynamially.I have all the icon classes for my icons defined in the interface like this

```
import { OpaqueToken } from "@angular/core";
import {IAppConfig} from './app.interface'

export let APP_CONFIG = new OpaqueToken("app.config");

export const AppConfig: IAppConfig = {    

employee:"circular tabbaricon users icon",
employee1:"circular tabbaricon users icon"
....etc

};
```

and the interface

```
export interface IAppConfig {

employee:string;
employee1:string;
}
```

I am importing this to my component using

```
constructor( @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: IAppConfig) { }
```

Now i have an ngFor where i have to display my data dynamically.ie based on the linkname i have to display appropriate icon.

```html
<div class="ui column" *ngFor="let x of funtionalities.routeLinks ">

<i class={{config+'.'+x.linkName}}  id="iconBack"></i>

</div>
```

ie how to display the icon .I want something like

```
 <i class={{config.x.linkName}}></i>
```

Is this possible to do any in way or is there any other way to achieve this?.Please help

Comment: have you tried with <i [class]="config.x.linkName"></i>

Comment: shows the error  Cannot read property 'linkName' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the view:

```
<div class="ui column" *ngFor="let x of funtionalities.routeLinks ">

   <i [ngClass]="getTheClass(x.linkName)"  id="iconBack"></i>

</div>
```

in the class:

```
import config from "./config.ts'
...
getTheClass(appendix){
    return config[appendix]
}
```

Comment: cant use this as i have to do something like class.x where x will be a variable from ngFor.

Comment: it dev tools it shows ng-reflect-ng-class="config.employee" which is right.But i want the value of config.employee ,ie i want {{config.employee}} to be assigned as the classs value..and no,ignore the iconBack